# Do $W$-conjugate characters induce the same modules under parabolic induction?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, algebraic-groups, characters

Suppose $G$ is an algebraic group, with maximal rational torus $T$, corresponding character group $X(T)$, and Weyl group $W$. Then $W$ acts on $X(T)$ via $(w\cdot \chi)(t)=\chi(t^w)$, where $t^w=w^{-1}tw$.

If $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$ are irreducible and conjugate under $W$ in $X(T)$, and $R_T^G$ denotes the parabolic induction functor, is it true that $R_T^G(\chi_1)$ and $R_T^G(\chi_2)$ are isomorphic as modules? (I'm blurring the distinction between characters and representations.)

Comment: It is too early in the day for me to work this out myself: Is this the same action as the one we "usually" consider on the characters, i.e. the one that comes from the action on the root system? Also, I am not particularly familiar with how parabolic induction works, but should you not start with a representation of a parabolic subgroup for that?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes, I think the action is the usual one we consider on characters. Parabolic induction is independent of the parabolic subgroup you choose, and is the same as inflating a representation of the Levi to a representation of a parabolic containing it, and then inducing to $G$ in the usual way. So I think we can start with the representation of $T$, and inflate and induct through any parabolic containing it as its Levi.

Comment: Ok, so we are really just doing induction from the Borel? But which induction? Is it the left- or the right adjoint of restriction?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes, inducting through the Borel. Left adjoint is fine. I'm sorry, I'm a little confused by your question since parabolic induction and restriction are biadjoint.

Comment: Restriction does not admit a biadjoint in the category of algebraic representations, so this suggests that this is not the category in which you work, which means it is something I don't know anything about.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft My apologies, I should be more specific, I'm looking at connected, reductive groups over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ in non-defining characteristic.

Comment: Once you are in non-defining characteristic we go way outside my knowledge. Is the geometry of the group even relevant any longer then, when we cannot define what it means for the representation to be algebraic?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Ah, I'm afraid I'm not qualified to say.